# Passing runtime version using Airflow operator to CMLE

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using the [MLEngine operator in contrib](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mlengine_operator.py) (could not find one in none contrib). The problem from the logs is runtime error which is not set properly and then defaults to 1.0.

> File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line
>   210, in train_and_evaluate estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn
>   = image_classifier, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'estimator'

I think this indicates I should be using TF 1.8 which I am as is indicated both in the trigger:

```
MLEngineTrainingOperator(
    task_id='ml_engine_training_op1',
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    job_id=job_id,
    package_uris=["gs://us-central1-ml-engine-deplo-0bf17ff3-bucket/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"],
    training_python_module=MODULE_NAME,
    training_args=training_args,
    region=REGION,
    scale_tier='BASIC',
    runtime_version = '1.8',
    dag=dag
)
```

And in the Airflow logs:

> PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to
>   MLEngineTrainingOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be
>   dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
>   *args: ()
>   **kwargs: {'runtime_version': '1.8'}

The version of airflow that is run by Cloud Composer is 1.9.

My question is what's the right way to pass in runtime version to CMLE using the operator?

Comment: Which airflow version are you using?

Comment: 1.9.0-composer - https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLEngineTrainingOperator in Airflow v1.9.0 doesn't support runtime_version as parameter.

However, The runtime_version parameter does exist in Airflow v1.10.0. You can use Composer Beta to create Airflow v.1.10.0 by checking `Enable Beta Features` in the upper-right corner on the Composer UI.

Reference:

[Airflow v1.9.0 mlengine_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/contrib/operators/mlengine_operator.py)

[Airflow v1.10.0 mlengine_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.0/airflow/contrib/operators/mlengine_operator.py)